# Mean and standard deviation in normal distribution and log-normal distribution

Tags: r, statistics

Below is my code:

```
set.seed(1)


par(mfrow=c(1,2))
lognorm.gen <- function(mu,sigma){
  ns <- rnorm(1000,mu,sigma)
  ns <- exp(ns)

  hist(ns,probability = T, main = expression(paste("Sample Density Curve", mu, sigma)))
  y <- seq(0,15,length=100)
  lines(y,dlnorm(y,mu,sigma))
}

lognorm.gen(0,0.25)
```

I generated samples from normal then transformed them into lognormal distribution.  Firstly, I am using `mu` and `sigma` as parameters in `rnorm()`, then I was supposed to use `exp(mu)` and `exp(sigma)` in `dlnorm()`. However, the plot showed that line and histogram are off a lot. Instead, `mu` and `sigma` in `dlnorm()` fit line into histogram well. So I am wondering why I shouldn't use `exp(mu)` in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please read `?dlnorm`:

```
 dlnorm(x, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1, log = FALSE)
 plnorm(q, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
 qlnorm(p, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1, lower.tail = TRUE, log.p = FALSE)
 rlnorm(n, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)

meanlog, sdlog: mean and standard deviation of the distribution on the
      log scale with default values of ‘0’ and ‘1’ respectively.
```

Mean and standard deviation are specified in **log scale**. That is why you still need the same `mu` and `sigma` as you used in `rnorm`, not `exp(mu)` and `exp(sigma)`.

Comment: I've read `?dlnorm` but I misunderstood how `meanlog()` works. Thanks for your help. By the way, if I want my title to show the exactly `mu` as the value input but not the two characters themselves, what should I change?

Comment: Is the function converting values to log scale or do you input the values in log scale? e.g. would you set the value for `meanlog` as `mean(x)` or `mean(log(x))`?

Comment: @daneshjai mean(log(x))